# add Woocommerce Bookings plugin's Availability (Add Range) feature to frontend create bookable product form (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wpuf(wp user frontend) forms plugin to allow a vendor to add his service(Bookable Product) to the website. Pretty much done with the form and product will get inserted to the Product list.

The only problem is admin or the vendor has to go back to the WP dashboard and add the time ranges for the booking to complete the book process. Until then the time and calendar to book the service wont show up.

I am unable to add this time range to wpuf forms and its headache to add a service from frontend form and update it again from backend dashboard.

Any help is appreciated... Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you could add hidden fields to your WPUF form to show the calendar always:

```
meta_key: _wc_booking_default_date_availability
meta_value: available
```

There is no plugin at the moment that allows submit availability information from the frontend. I'm in the same scenario, waiting for WC Vendor PRO 1.4.0 version.
I hope it helps.

Regards,